# Google Map API recenter upon checkbox action jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

*Hello everyone,*

I have been working on a google map html but I am having some difficulty in reloading the map as an action for my checkbox. I am simply trying to reposition the map. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type = "text/css">
      html, body{height: 90%;width: 90%;padding: 5px;margin: auto;}
      #googleMap {height: 90%; width: 90%; padding: 5px; margin: auto;}
      #left_check {position: absolute;left: 10%;}
      #padded-left {position: absolute;padding-left: 1.4em;}
      #right_check{float: right; }
      #mid_check {text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
      #left_align {display: inline-block;text-align: left;}
    </style>

    <script type = "text/javascript" 
     src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
    </script>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'> </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.location').click(function(){
        $(".location").removeProp("checked");
        $(this).prop("checked","checked");
    });
  
    $('#canada1').click(function() {
        if ($('#canada1').is(':checked')) {
            alert('Canada is checked');
            var canadaPos = new google.maps.LatLng(58.1707, -97.6289);

            map.setOptions({
                center: canadaPos,
            });
        };
  });


});

    function initialize() {
        var mapProperties = 
         {
         // Center Map on specified Lat/Lng and set default zoom
            center: { lat: 41.5, lng: -88},
            zoom: 4
            };
            //creating the map object
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProperties);
      
      
     
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

    </head>


    <body>
      <div id="googleMap"> </div>

      <ul style = "list-style-type:none">

        <div id = "left_check">
          <li> 
              <form>
                  <input type ="checkbox" name ="location" value ="united_states"> United States (domestic) <br>

                  <div id = "padded-left">
                    <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="west_coast"> West <br>
                    <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="central_us"> East <br>
                    <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="east_coast"> Central
                  </div>
              </form>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div id = "right_check">
          <li>
              <form>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="europe"> Europe <br>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="africa"> Africa <br>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="asia"> Asia <br>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="australia"> Australia
              </form>
          </li>
        </div>

        <div id = "mid_check">
        <div id = "left_align">
          <li>
              <form>
                  <input id ="canada1" type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="canada"> Canada <br>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="central_america"> Central America <br>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="south_america"> South America <br>
                  <input type ="checkbox" class ="location" value ="south_america"> Oceanic
              </form>
          </li>
        </div>
        </div>

      </ul>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this seems a job for radio buttons not for checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dynamically change the center of your map without reload it:

```
var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

map.setCenter(newPos);

map.panTo(newPos);

map.panBy(xpixel,ypixel);

map.panToBounds(newBounds);
```

these are the methods to change the map center ( [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) )

Comment: Thank you. This was a great hint, and I appreciate the suggestion for radio buttons but I hope to build on to the functionality of the action :)

Comment: May I ask how would I go about with this implementation? I edited my initial post to attempt this method but the only resulting action is the alert.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to learn how to add the functionality I wanted. In order to accomplish this, I placed the jQuery code below the initialize function because that is where the map object was declared. I was wondering how it was possible that the post below was able to use map.panTo without having first done this. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you try to add 'load' event for window on checkbox checking, but this event fires on first page load and doesn't fire when you click on your checkbox.

I mean this line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', reinitialize);
```

You can try to force this event after line above:

```
$(window).trigger('load');
```

OR just execute your function:

```
$('#canada1').click(function() {
        if ($('#canada1').is(':checked')) {
            alert('Canada is checked');
            function reinitialize() {
                var canada1map = 
                {
                center: { lat: 58.1707, lng: -97.6289},
                zoom: 4
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), canada1map);
            };

            reinitialize();
        };

  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I do appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type = "text/css">
  html, body{height: 90%;width: 90%;padding: 5px;margin: auto;}
  #googleMap {height: 90%; width: 90%; padding: 5px; margin: auto;}
  #left_check {position: absolute;left: 10%;}
  #padded-left {position: absolute;padding-left: 1.4em;}
  #right_check{float: right; }
  #mid_check {text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
  #left_align {display: inline-block;text-align: left;}
</style>

<script type = "text/javascript" 
 src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script type = "text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'> </script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [{lat: 45, lng: -90},{lat: 30, lng: -100},{lat: 40, lng: -80},{lat: 40, lng: -95}];
    $(".location").click(function(){
         $(".location").removeProp("checked");
         $(this).prop("checked","checked");
         
         map.panTo(data[$(this).attr("data-location")]);
   });
   


});

function initialize() {
    var mapProperties = 
     {
     // Center Map on specified Lat/Lng and set default zoom
        center: { lat: 42, lng: -87},
        zoom: 4
        };
        //creating the map object
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProperties);
  
  
 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>


<body>
  <div id="googleMap"> </div>

  <ul style = "list-style-type:none">

    <div id = "left_check">
      <li> 
          <form>
              <input class="location" data-location="0" type ="checkbox" name ="location" > United States (domestic) <br>

              <div id = "padded-left">
                <input class="location" data-location="1" type ="checkbox"  value ="west_coast"> West <br>
                <input class="location" data-location="2" type ="checkbox"  value ="central_us"> East <br>
                <input class="location" data-location="3" type ="checkbox"  value ="east_coast"> Central
              </div>
          </form>
      </li>
    </div>

    <div id = "right_check">
      <li>
          <form>
              <input class="location" data-location="0" type ="checkbox"  value ="europe"> Europe <br>
              <input class="location" data-location="1" type ="checkbox"  value ="africa"> Africa <br>
              <input class="location" data-location="2" type ="checkbox"  value ="asia"> Asia <br>
              <input class="location" data-location="3" type ="checkbox"  value ="australia"> Australia
          </form>
      </li>
    </div>

    <div id = "mid_check">
    <div id = "left_align">
      <li>
          <form>
              <input class="location" data-location="0" id ="canada1" type ="checkbox"  value ="canada"> Canada <br>
              <input class="location" data-location="1" type ="checkbox"  value ="central_america"> Central America <br>
              <input class="location" data-location="2" type ="checkbox"  value ="south_america"> South America <br>
              <input class="location" data-location="3" type ="checkbox"  value ="south_america"> Oceanic
          </form>
      </li>
    </div>
    </div>

  </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely try this

Comment: Thank you for teaching me how to easily remove that checked property!

Comment: May I ask how you were able to call map.panTo prior to the map object being declared? I need to move my jQuery after the initialize function in order for it to work.